# Finding more than one distinct attribute in a Correlated Subquery

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to understand correlated subquery's and cannot get my head around this question. I need to list all information on bookjobs which have POS data for more than one distinct vendor.

I must use a correlated subquery on job_id.
I cannot use group by or having either.

```
SELECT *
FROM bookjobs a
WHERE EXISTS 
            (SELECT DISTINCT vendor_id 
             FROM pos b 
             WHERE b.job_id = a.job_id);

job_id      cust_id     job_date    descr       jobtype
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
002         E05         1990-03-03  BUS REPORT  N
004         A01         1990-01-01  PAMPHLETS   R
005         A01         1989-11-23  GOVT        N
006         D04         1988-07-04  CAMPAIGN    H
```

I cannot use this for the question either:

```
SELECT *
FROM bookjobs a
WHERE EXISTS 
             (SELECT job_id 
              FROM pos b 
              WHERE b.job_id = a.job_id 
              GROUP BY job_id 
              HAVING COUNT(job_id) > 1 );

job_id      cust_id     job_date    descr       jobtype
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
002         E05         1990-03-03  BUS REPORT  N
004         A01         1990-01-01  PAMPHLETS   R
005         A01         1989-11-23  GOVT        N
```

SCHEMA

```
CREATE TABLE pos (
  po_id     CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
  job_id    CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
  po_date   DATE,
  vendor_id CHAR(3),

  PRIMARY KEY (po_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (job_id) REFERENCES bookjobs(job_id)

CREATE TABLE bookjobs (
  job_id   CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
  cust_id  CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
  job_date DATE,
  descr    CHAR(10),
  jobtype  CHAR(1),

  PRIMARY KEY (job_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (cust_id) REFERENCES publishers(cust_id)
```

The expected results should be:

```
job_id      cust_id     job_date    descr       jobtype
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
002         E05         1990-03-03  BUS REPORT  N
004         A01         1990-01-01  PAMPHLETS   R
005         A01         1989-11-23  GOVT        N
```

Comment: a and b are poor table aliases. Chose something that makes some sense, e.g. `bj` for **b**ook**j**obs.

Comment: *I must use a correlated subquery on job_id. I cannot use group by or having either.* ... Due to an assignment or your preference?

Comment: Its not a assignment Per se more like questions to help understand SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM bookjobs a
WHERE ( SELECT COUNT(1)
          FROM pos b 
         WHERE b.job_id = a.job_id  ) >= 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try counting the venders in the where clause WHEN Grouped By the JobId

```
SELECT
     *
FROM
    BookJobs AS B
WHERE
    EXISTS 
        (
        SELECT 
            P.JobId
            ,Count (Vender)
        FROM 
            Pos P
        WHERE
            P.JobId = B.JobId
        Group By 
            P.JobId
        HAVING 
            Count(Vender) > 1
        )
```